# Amazon Redshift: `ActiveStatementsExceededException` (how to do INSERTs concurrently)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis

I have a Kinesis cluster that's pushing data into Amazon Redshift via Lambda.

Currently my lambda code looks something like this:

```py
client = boto3.client('redshift-data')
for tx in txs:
    query = # prepare an INSERT query here

    resp = client.execute_statement(
        ClusterIdentifier=redshift_cluster_id,
        Database=redshift_db,
        DbUser=redshift_user,
        Sql=query
    )
```

The trouble is that as soon as I try to scale up kinesis (more shards) or lambda (concurrent procesing from a single shard) - I get this:

```
[ERROR] ActiveStatementsExceededException: An error occurred (ActiveStatementsExceededException) when calling the ExecuteStatement operation: Active statements exceeded the allowed quota (200).
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/codeguru_profiler_agent/aws_lambda/profiler_decorator.py", line 52, in profiler_decorate
    return function(event, context)
  File "/opt/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/codeguru_profiler_agent/aws_lambda/lambda_handler.py", line 91, in call_handler
    return handler_function(event, context)
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 71, in lambda_handler
    resp = client.execute_statement(
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 386, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/var/runtime/botocore/client.py", line 705, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
```

From AWS docs I gather this means I'm trying to run too many `execute_statement`s in parallel.

How do I get around this? Is the only way to work with Redshift by batching records and inserting them all together?

Comment: you really cannot use inserts like that to update redshift - it will be far too slow, unless you have an very low volume. You need to write batches to s3 then use the readshift bulk load processes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comment in your code gives me pause - "query = # prepare an INSERT query here".  This seems to imply that you are reading the S3 data into Lambda and INSERTing the this data into Redshift.  If so this is not a good pattern.

First off Redshift expects data to be brought into the cluster through COPY (or Spectrum or ...) but not through INSERT.  This will create issues in Redshift with managing the transactions and create a tremendous waste or disk space / need for VACUUM.  The INSERT approach for putting data in Redshift is an anti-pattern and shouldn't be done for even moderate sizes of data.

More generally the concern is the data movement impedance mismatch. Kinesis is lots of independent streams of data and code generating small files.  Redshift is a massive database that works on large data segments.  Mismatching these tools in a way that misses their designed targets will make either of them perform very poorly.  You need to match the data requirement by batching up S3 into Redshift.  This means COPYing many S3 files into Redshift in a single COPY command.  This can be done with manifests or by "directory" structure in S3.  "COPY everything from S3 path ..."  This process of COPYing data into Redshift can be run every time interval (2 or 5 or 10 minutes).  So you want your Kinesis Lambdas to organize the data in S3 (or add to a manifest) so that a "batch" of S3 files can be collected up for a COPY execution.  This way a large number of S3 files can be brought into Redshift at once (its preferred data size) and will also greatly reduce your execute API calls.

Now if you have a very large Kinesis pipe set up and the data is very large there is another data movement "preference" to take into account.  This only matters when you are moving a lot of data per minute.  This extra preference is for S3.  S3 being an object store means that there is a significant amount of time taken up by "looking up" a requested object key.  It is about .5 sec.  So reading a thousand S3 objects will take 500 require (in total) 500 seconds of key lookup time.  Redshift will make requests to S3 in parallel, one per slice in the cluster, so some of this time is in parallel.  If the files being read are 1KB in size the data transfer of the data, after S3 lookup is complete, will be about 1.25 sec. total.  Again this time is in parallel but you can see how much time is spent in lookup vs. transfer.  To get the maximum bandwidth out of S3 for reading many files, these files need to be 1GB in size (100MB is ok in my experience).  You can see if you are to ingest millions of files per minute from Kinesis into Redshift you will need a process to combine many small files into bigger files to avoid this hazard of S3.  Since you are using Lambda as your Kinesis reader I expect that you aren't to this data rate yet but it is good to have your eyes on this issue if you expect to expand to a very large scale.

Just because tools have high bandwidth doesn't mean that they can be piped together.  Bandwidth comes in many styles.

Comment: thanks a lot for the exhaustive reply. Quick follow up question - so there's no way to do streaming data direct into redshift? I'd like it to update real-time. You are 100% correct in assuming I don't have much experience with redshift, and am unfamiliar with anti-patterns. What's the appropriate solution for a real-time updating OLAP datastore on AWS?

Comment: If you truly mean "real time" (up to the second) then a OLAP DB is not going to provide a complete solution.  These are great with massive amounts of data but come with some cost in "prepping" the data so it can be analyzed quickly at this scale.  What I have set up clients before is a hybrid approach for when they need "real-time" and "massively historical" at the same time.  First I'd look at Kinesis Analytics and see if this can provide the real-time analysis you are looking for.  It is limited so review carefully.  You can then merge Kinesis Analytics with Redshift in several ways. Or ...

Comment: Kinesis Analytics looks at the data as it is flowing through the stream but if you can wait for the data to be live in S3 then you can use Redshift Spectrum to query "recent" data while "older" data is native in Redshift.  This way only a small amount of data queried is in Spectrum while most is in Redshift (local) tables.  Then a view can be used to combine the data.  Every time interval (hour, day) data is brought into Redshift and the amount of data queried from Spectrum is reduced.

Comment: And one new way to do this would be with Redshift Federated Queries.  The recent data could be in RDS Postgres which has higher (but is it high enough) data write rate.  Then the "older" data can be moved to Redshift (daily?).

Comment: nice so sonds like kinesis > RDS > redshift. What do you think about keeping it in S3 and querying with athena? I was gonna go with that approahc but got worried it'd be hard to unite with other data that is not in s3 (eg tabular price data in redshift)

Comment: So much about your requirements are not clear to me.  Take with a grain of salt as I'm using assumptions.  Athena is great for occasional queries at low cost.  This doesn't seem to be your use pattern so I'd advise Redshift plus Redshift Spectrum over Athena alone for higher workloads.  Both Athena and Spectrum have access to data as soon as it is written to S3 so their timeliness of data is the same.  If you have a high query rate Athena can get expensive as you are paying per query.  Since older data is brought into Redshift, Spectrum only has a minority of the data so this combo is faster.

Comment: Combining Redshift Spectrum data with Redshift native data is simple as you just need to create a view that spans both the internal and external tables.  You query the view and Redshift takes care of the combining.  Since some overlap is possible your view will need to have WHERE clauses in your view that ensures the same data isn't read from both.

Comment: Similarly combining data for Federated Queries is done with a view.  In this case one source of data is the RDS database and the other is the Redshift internal table.  The enclosing view would be almost the same.  I believe that Spectrum will be slightly faster and cheaper as there isn't a second database engine in the loop.  The upside to Federated Query is that RDS is an OLTP database and better able to handle the write bandwidth you currently have coming from your Lambdas.

Comment: All I can do is point out advantages and disadvantages of different approaches.  Getting to a recommended approach will mean mapping requirements (including cost) against these approaches.  All I can recommend for sure is that you don't want to have a high rate of UPDATES sent to Redshift - it's a read-often / write-infrequently database that does best with writes for big batches of data.

Comment: Thanks so much for the detailed commentary. Really appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome.  Setting up such solutions is what I do.  Answering 'how' questions is my way of paying it forward.